# How to automatically start a Torque animation using Carto Builder

Tags: carto

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Torque animation to start automatically when my map is loaded. Here is a sample map:

[Torque Map with Carto Builder](https://maxhartshorn.carto.com/builder/5bc3e784-ff74-40ef-8ae0-9fa85b6e13fa/embed?state=%7B%22map%22%3A%7B%22ne%22%3A%5B34.813803317113155%2C-177.5390625%5D%2C%22sw%22%3A%5B74.54332982677906%2C-16.523437500000004%5D%7D%7D)

I know this was possible with the old Carto Editor ([see here](https://srogers.carto.com/viz/337d9194-6458-11e3-85b5-e5e70547d141/public_map?__hstc=124960853.9d9d77171717d0b22c62542d54a62d81.1491490129425.1491490129425.1491490129425.1&__hssc=124960853.27.1491490129426&__hsfp=1283505112)) but I can't figure out how to do it with the new tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a BUILDER animated layer within an embed map should be activated by the final user.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Is it on the roadmap? Is there a way to accomplish this with the API?

Comment: That's funny because lots of users in GIS SE asked to be able to start their Torque visualizations, and now it looks like it is going to be the other way around. You can still use CARTO.js `createLayer` with Torque and set the loading options as explained [here](https://carto.com/academy/courses/cartojs-ground-up/torquejs#pulling-it-all-together).

Comment: Thanks. Having the option for both would be ideal. A common use case would be a user who has no experience with Carto viewing a torque map. He/She may not know to click play to view the animation, or that there is an animation. The click to play approach currently in place makes several assumptions about the user.

Comment: CARTO is an OS product. If you think this is a cool/useful feature request, you can add an issue to [the main repository](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb), thus adding as many details and uses cases as possible.